# get,set and value keyword in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

What is `value` keyword here and how is it assigning the value to `_num`? I'm pretty     confused, please give the description for the following code.

```
    private int _num;
    public int num
    { 
        get 
        {
            return _num;
        }
        set 
        {
            _num=value;
        }
    }

    public void button1_click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        num = numericupdown.Value;
    }
```

Comment: Read more about [accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 22):

In the context of a property setter, the `value` keyword represents the value being assigned to the property. It's actually an implicit parameter of the `set` accessor, as if it was declared like this:

```
private int _num
public int num
{ 
    get 
    {
        return _num;
    }
    set(int value)
    {
        _num=value;
    }
}
```

Property accessors are actually methods equivalent to those:

```
public int get_num()
{
    return _num;
}

public void set_num(int value)
{
    _num = value;
}
```

Comment: But how exacly does the computer decide what value the "value" holds?

Comment: @CopperKettle it's the value assigned to the property. If you do `num = 42`, then `value` is 42.

Comment: Thank you! I tinkered with the code for half an hour and understood it. I totally missed the point that the value is assigned somewhere else, in case of need, and not inside the set declaration itself.

Comment: @CopperKettle glad I could help!

Answer (score 8):

The [value keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1khb4f8.aspx) is a *contextual keyword*, that is, it has a different meaning based on its context.

Inside a `set` block, it simply means the value that the programmer has set it to. For instance,

```
className.num = 5;
```

In this case, `value` would be equal to 5 *inside of the `set` block*. So you could write:

```
set
{
    int temp = value; //temp = 5
    if (temp == 5) //true
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    _num = value;
}
```

Outside of a `set` block, you can use `value` as a variable identifier, as such:

```
int value = 5;
```

Note that you **cannot** do this inside a `set` block.

Side note: You should capitalize the property `num` to `Num`; this is a common convention that makes it easier for someone who's reading your class to identify public and private properties.

Comment: ok i understand value keyword holds some value which is assigned to the variable _num in the set block and returns _num to the calling function in the get block,i still dont understand how the value to the value keyword is assigned and what if i initialize two different variables int and string with the value keyword

Answer (score 2):

`Properties` are the way you can READ, WRITE or COMPUTE values of a `private field` or `class variable`.
The `set` or `setter` inside a `property` is used when the code assigns a value into the `private field` or (class) `variable`.
The `value` keyword means simply "the thing that is being assigned".

```
    public class StaffMember 
    { 
        private int ageValue; 
        public int Age 
            { 
                 set 
                     { 
                         if ( (value > 0) && (value < 120) ) 
                             { this.ageValue = value; } 
                     } 
                 get { 
                      return this.ageValue; 
                     } 
            } 
    }
//Rob Miles - C# Programming Yellow Book
```